# No resource identifier found for attribute 'Orientation' in package 'android'

Tags: android, xml

the xml code is like this:

```
LinearLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

  android:Orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: It's `orientation` - all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
 <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
     <!-- You Elements -->
 </LinearLayout>
```